# Using function keys as Photoshop shortcuts

Tags: windows, adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I was trying to add keyboard shortcuts to Photoshop CS5, after watching the [ctrlpaint tutorial](http://www.ctrlpaint.com/home/2012/3/8/brush-agility.html), using function keys. I was able to map F3, F4 and F5 to Zoom Out, Zoom In and Fit to Screen just fine.

I think I closed Photoshop and opened again, and tried to assign other function keys but it now says, on trying to assign:

```
F3 is an invalid shortcut. The F-key cannot be used.
```

for *any* of the function keys, even if I try to assign the F3-5 again. I read on the Adobe website that F1 can't be used, which is fine, but I'm uncertain why the others won't assign anymore.

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit and Photoshop CS5 Extended, with a UK keyboard layout (and Microsoft Keyboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to assign the function key to `Foreground Picker` which is under the tools menu; if you select a standard tool and attempt to assign a function key to it, it gives a different error message:

```
F2 is an invalid shortcut. You can only use A-Z for tool shortcuts
```

which would have been more helpful than the original message which you get. That said, you can assign shortcuts with function keys to commands in the Application Menus tab like `Layer > New > Layer` etc.

Comment: I'll mark this as answer when I come back to the site next, unless there are any better ones.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could answer your own questions on this site :P

Comment: it's a good feature in case you figure out the answer and others come looking for the same question in the future, but I can see how it could be abused..! I guess there's some mechanism to stop people from constantly doing it :)